# batch command "skip=2 Delims="

Tags: batch-file, makefile

I had the below code in one of the make files.

```
@for /F "skip=2 Delims=" %%i in ('<somefile>') do echo Code-%%i
```

Could anybody tell what is this batch command would do?

Comment: `for /F` loop is used to perform operation  upon a set of files, here your filenameset  `('')`  is empty. So actually this line does nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it is written

```
@for /F "skip=2 Delims=" %%i in ('<somefile>') do echo Code-%%i
```

this means: Execute (not read file, execute, there are simple quotes) `<somefile>`, take its output to standard stream, skip the two first lines, and for each line with content, assign this line contents to %%i, then, also for each line, output to console the text `Code-` followed by the content of the readed line (that is inside %%i).

The `@` at the start of the line means not to echo to console the `for` command.

The delims with no value assigned indicates that lines should not be considered as a concatenation of fields with a delimiter between them, that have to be splitted.